# libcurl - on HTTP 500 error use a new connection using curl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I'm using libcURL. I have used `curl_easy_setopt` to set `CURLOPT_URL` and `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. I have then got the response successfully using `curl_easy_perform`.

Now libcURL manual says "Options set with this function call are valid for all forthcoming transfers performed using this handle. The options are not in any way reset between transfers, so if you want subsequent transfers with different options, you must change them between the transfers."

I want to be able to reset connection between transfer ONLY if I see a HTTP 500 error if not I do not want to reset connection.

I have the code in place to check if its HTTP 500 error or not. Could anyone tell me how I can reset connection in such a case.

Please note: I do not want to reset connection in all subsequent transfers BUT ONLY the next immediate transfer to when I see a HTTP 500 error.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "reset connection" ? What is it that you want the connection to do then?